# Why can a new user not write to external Hard Drive?

Tags: permissions, users, external-hdd

I installed Precise Pangolin using this [guide](http://www.havetheknowhow.com/Install-Ubuntu.html). I created a user account for my wife and a guest account. I formatted and mounted an external hard drive to the server. I created several file shares using Webmin as per the guide.

All file shares are set to writable; with valid users: myself and wife (some also have guest as valid user). I was initially unable to write to any share with any account. I ran `chown -R /directory/to/myshare` (using the correct directory path of course) and was able to write to the specific share with my account.

I set file permissions to 775 (in webmin) and am still unable to write using wife account. Accounts are under group: Users.
What else can I try to allow wife account to write?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a groups problem. Certain groups are allowed to do certain things. If your not in the club you don't get to play. Try running the `groups` command with both users:

```
 groups [USERNAME]...
```

If your wife is not a member of the necessary group then just run:

```
gpasswd -a [user] [group]
```

Comment: I used Webmin to give wife account the same secondary group permissions I have (adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare.) We are both part of primary group: users. She still is denied access to write to the ext HD. I tried to run gpasswd -a [user] [group] using putty and got the message, "Gpasswd: permission denied." On a slightly unrelated note, I can no longer see my server on the network (I could when I first installed). I can still open the drive that I mapped prior, but cannot see the server itself. I'll open a separate help ticket for that.

Comment: After the last couple updates I now have server visibility thought Windows. I noticed I can write to some shares with wife's account but not all. I can write to all shares with my account. I spent a lot of time checking setting between the shares and could not find any differences. All shares appear to have the same permissions.